# Strong parameters raises 'stack level too deep' in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm moving my rails 3.2 app from the default mass assignment protection to strong parameters. I've disabled *whitelist_attributes* in my application.rb and added the required include statement in my models.

In my controller I permit the proper attributes when I create a model.

```
def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  ...
end

protected
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :locale, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

This works fine in development and in production. But for some reason in my test environment it breaks. I use a functional test for the create action which does a simple post with a hash. I get an 'stack level too deep' on 2nd line in the above code fragment.

```
  1) Error:
test_should_get_create(UsersControllerTest):
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    /home/martijn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23
```

This doesn't only happen in my controller. It also happens when I call functions such as update_attributes in a model or in the test code. But in development it works fine.

It also works when I remove *include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection*.

Any ideas?